# django-import-export error while importing data into database through Admin Panel

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-import-export

I am facing this error:
I am using the django-import-export package.
The trouble is I can't find much in the way of docs on the import side of things and I'd like to be able to use it to import data into my we app.

```sh
Line number: 1 - 'id'
1, 2021-03-02 05:12:24, 2021-03-02 05:12:24, 0, name, email, 01999999999, text, 161, 303, 76744, 14, address, 2020-11-26, dddd, SHD, PM, 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/mikegreat/Documents/cop411/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/import_export/resources.py", line 497, in import_row
instance, new = self.get_or_init_instance(instance_loader, row)
File "/Users/mikegreat/Documents/cop411/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/import_export/resources.py", line 274, in get_or_init_instance
instance = self.get_instance(instance_loader, row)
File "/Users/mikegreat/Documents/cop411/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/import_export/resources.py", line 268, in get_instance
return instance_loader.get_instance(row)
File "/Users/mikegreat/Documents/cop411/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/import_export/instance_loaders.py", line 28, in get_instance
field = self.resource.fields[key]
KeyError: 'id'
```

This is my Excel Sheet File:
[image]

This is my ModelResource

```py
class IncidenceReport(resources.ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        model = Incidence

        skip_unchanged = True
        report_skipped = True
        import_id_fields = ['id']
        fields = ('country__name', 'state__name', 'city__name', 'created_at', 'updated_at',
                  'reporter_name', 'reporter_email', 'reporter_phone', 'description',
                  'street_address', 'date_of_incidence', 'name_of_officers',)


class IncidenceAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    resource_class = IncidenceReport
    autocomplete_fields = ("country", "state", "city")
    list_display = [field.name for field in Incidence._meta.fields]
    search_fields = ['country__name', 'state__name', 'city__name', 'description',
                     'street_address', 'is_rep_needed', 'is_victim']
    list_filter = ('created_at', 'updated_at',  'is_rep_needed', 'is_victim')
```

Answer (score 0):

It's likely happening because you don't list 'id' (i.e. the `import_id_fields` value) in your field list:

```py
class IncidenceReport(resources.ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        model = Incidence

        skip_unchanged = True
        report_skipped = True
        import_id_fields = ['id']
        # declare 'id' in this tuple:
        fields = ('id', 'country__name', ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issue.
The problem was that I added the id field on the excel sheet